# how to write custom converter to write List<employee> in file in apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

I have one scenario where I am getting the data from table using below  mentioned  mybastis code 
Producer template
List list=producerTemplate.requestBody(
                    "direct:select", null, List.class);
And rote code

```
public class IntegrationRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("direct:select").to("mybatis:listBillDataFetch?statementType=SelectList");

        from("direct:fileExport").process(new MyProcessor()).to("file:target/reports/report.txt");

    }
}
```

It is fetching data perfectly in List from the database but while I am storing the data in file I am getting below mentioned exception 
java.util.ArrayList to the required type: java.io.InputStream
I am new to in apache camel if someone can tell me how to write List in file, I google it and found need to write custom convertor , can someone please tell me how to write custom convertor for this situation

```
public class Employee {

    private String empId;

    private String empName;

    public String getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(String empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to think about what structure your data should be in that text file. Should it for example be in CSV format or XML or what should it be. Only then you should look at how to transform the List to that structure, maybe you can use existing data formats in Camel to do so, or you need to write some custom logic.

Comment: it should be comma separated column in text file, it easily write through marshal if i am fetching data from sql database , its creating only problem with mybatis

Comment: You can add a toString in your POJO class where you separate the values in CSV format. Then you can use the Splitter EIP to split the list and write each row to the file. You can then use convertBodyTo(string) to convert the POJO to string (which calls your toString method) that then can be written to the file. Remember to set fileExists=Append so the rows are appended to the file.

Comment: How can i use pojo column name as header in my txt file

Comment: Check camel-beanio you can configure using xml and define how the text output should look like.

Comment: Yeah you may want to look at bindy, beanio, csv, flatmap etc for CSV mapping